# Class scope variabile visibility

Tags: java

If I have:

```
class A
{
   void foo()
   {
      int a = count;      
   }

   void bar()
   {
      int a = c; // here ERROR
      int c = 10;
   }

   private int count = 10;

}
```

here in `foo` `count` is used without problem also if it's declared after the use.
The same is not true in method `bar` where the variable `c` must be declared before its
use.

Which are the class scope rules? How they differs from method scope rules?

P.S.
My doubt is because the common scope resolutions rules:
When the compiler find `count` it should try to find it "back" to its
use but back there is `Class A...` so maybe `private int count` is "hoisting" at
beginning of `Class A`?

Comment: what is `c`? you need to declare it first or make it a member field first

Comment: Why dont u declare c before a ,and then see,what happens

Comment: Read all about scopes in Java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you were a compiler, and you get to the line:

```
int a = c;
```

Won't you get angry and ask yourself "What is `c`"? The order is important<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>`count` doesn't make a problem because it's a [class member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), it's known in the whole class. You can place *class members* in the beginning of the class, or at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`count` is declared in the class while `c` is declared in the method

While compiling, the class would find `count` in the class.

```
class A
{
   void foo()
   {
      int a = count;      
   }
   private int count = 10;
}
```

is equal to put `count` anywhere in the class, as it is a class member and can be found in the class everywhere.

while in your case of

```
class A
{
   void bar()
   {
      int a = c; // here ERROR
      int c = 10;
   }
}
```

`c` is not defined before use, as `c` is a local variable in a method.